# numpy matrix algebra best practice

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

My question is regarding the last line below: `mu@sigma@mu`. Why does it work? Is a one-dimensional ndarray treated as a row vector or a column vector? Either way, shouldn't it be `mu.T@sigma@mu` or `mu@sigma@mu.T`? I know `mu.T` still returns `mu` since `mu` only has one dimension, but still, the interpreter seems to be too smart.

```
>> import numpy as np
>> mu = np.array([1, 1])
>> print(mu)

[1 1]

>> sigma = np.eye(2) * 3
>> print(sigma)

[[ 3.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.]]

>> mu@sigma@mu

6.0
```

More generally, which is a better practice for matrix algebra in python: use ndarray and `@` to do matrix multiplication as above (cleaner code), or use `np.matrix` and the overloaded `*` as below (mathematically less confusing)

```
>> import numpy as np
>> mu = np.matrix(np.array([1, 1]))
>> print(mu)

[[1 1]]

>> sigma = np.matrix(np.eye(2) * 3)
>> print(sigma)

[[ 3.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.]]

>> a = mu * sigma * mu.T
>> a.item((0, 0))

6.0
```

Comment: [Here are the docs.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) They're kind of hard to find if you don't already know the right terms.

Comment: Also the [recommended `@` semantics](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/#semantics) in the @ PEP.

Comment: This is not really a Python operator but a Numpy operator. You can find the documentation about it here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul

Comment: To be precise: `@` is a python operator, but this question is about the numpy's _implementation_ of that python operator.

Comment: I've added some notes on transpose and inner v outer products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python performs chained operations left to right:

```
In [32]: mu=np.array([1,1])
In [33]: sigma= np.array([[3,0],[0,3]])
In [34]: mu@sigma@mu
Out[34]: 6
```

is the same as doing two expressions:

```
In [35]: temp=mu@sigma
In [36]: temp.shape
Out[36]: (2,)
In [37]: temp@mu
Out[37]: 6
```

In my comments (deleted) I claimed `@` was just doing `np.dot`.  That's not quite right.  The documentation describes the handling of 1d arrays differently.  But the resulting shapes are the same:

```
In [38]: mu.dot(sigma).dot(mu)
Out[38]: 6
In [39]: mu.dot(sigma).shape
Out[39]: (2,)
```

For 1d and 2d arrays, `np.dot` and `@` should produce the same result.  They differ in handling higher dimensional arrays.

Historically numpy has used arrays, which can be 0d, 1d, and on up.  `np.dot` was the original matrix multiplication method/function.

`np.matrix` was added, largely as a convenience for wayward MATLAB programmers.  It only allows 2d arrays (just as the old, 1990s MATLAB).  And it overloads `__mat__` (*) with

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, (N.ndarray, list, tuple)) :
        # This promotes 1-D vectors to row vectors
        return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
    if isscalar(other) or not hasattr(other, '__rmul__') :
        return N.dot(self, other)
    return NotImplemented
```

`Mu*sigma` and `Mu@sigma` behave the same, though the calling tree is different

```
In [48]: Mu@sigma@Mu
...
ValueError: shapes (1,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

`Mu*sigma` produces a (1,2) matrix, which cannot matrix multiply a (1,2), hence the need for a transpose:

```
In [49]: Mu@sigma@Mu.T
Out[49]: matrix([[6]])
```

Note that this is a (1,1) matrix.  You have to use `item` if you want a scalar.  (In MATLAB there isn't such a thing as a scalar. Everything has a shape/size.)

`@` is a relatively recent addition to Python and numpy.  It was added to Python as an unimplemented operator.  numpy (and possibly other packages) has implemented it.

It makes chained expressions possible, though I don't have any problems with the chained `dot` in `[38]`.  It is more useful when handling higher dimensional cases.

This addition means there is one less reason to use the old `np.matrix` class.  (Matrix like behavior is more deeply ingrained in the `scipy.sparse` matrix classes.)

If you want 'mathematical purity' I'd suggest taking the mathematical physics approach, and use Einstein notation - as implemented in `np.einsum`.

---

With arrays this small, the timings reflect the calling structure more than the actually number of calculations:

```
In [57]: timeit mu.dot(sigma).dot(mu)
2.79 µs ± 7.75 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [58]: timeit mu@sigma@mu
6.29 µs ± 31.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [59]: timeit Mu@sigma@Mu.T
17.1 µs ± 134 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [60]: timeit Mu*sigma*Mu.T
17.7 µs ± 517 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Note that the 'old-fashioned' `dot` is fastest, while both matrix versions are slower.

### On the transpose

I might add that in an expression like `mu@sigma@mu.T`, the `.T` is evaluated first, so the `@` (`matmul`) does not know that there was an attempt to transpose `mu`.  It just uses the result of the transpose.  Remember it's the Python interpreter that parses the expression, not the `numpy` functions.  So if `mu.T` does nothing to `mu`, as is the case with 1d arrays, the `.T` will have no effect in the `@` either.

`transpose` is well defined for 2d arrays.  The `numpy` transpose has been written in such a way that it also works with arrays of any dimension.  It changes the order of the axes, but never adds a dimension.  There are other tools for doing that, such as `reshape` and the `np.newaxis` indexing.

In Octave, transpose is defined only for 2-d objects

```
>> ones(2,3,4)'
error: transpose not defined for N-d objects
```

1-d objects don't exist in MATLAB.

```
In [270]: np.ones((2,3,4),int).T.shape
Out[270]: (4, 3, 2)
```

### Inner and Outer products

`np.dot` is quite explicit about how it handles 1d arrays, 'vectors':

> - If both `a` and `b` are 1-D arrays, it is inner product of vectors
>     (without complex conjugation).

In `matmul` the description is more convoluted, but the result is the same.

Regarding your comment:

> A = [1, 2] and B = [3, 5] being (2, ) ndarray, A@B could mean [1, 2] * [3, 5]' = 13, or it could mean [1, 2]' * [3, 5] = [[3, 5], [6, 10]]

The various ways of taking a product in `numpy` are:

```
In [273]: A = np.array([1,2]); B = np.array([3,5])
```

Element multiplication (`.*` in MATLAB)

```
In [274]: A*B
Out[274]: array([ 3, 10])
```

Inner product

```
In [275]: A@B       # same as np.dot(A,B)
Out[275]: 13
```

Outer product

```
In [276]: np.outer(A,B)
Out[276]: 
array([[ 3,  5],
       [ 6, 10]])
```

Another way to get the inner product:

```
In [278]: np.sum(A*B)
Out[278]: 13
```

With Einstein notation (from math physics), both inner and outer:

```
In [280]: np.einsum('i,i',A,B)
Out[280]: array(13)
In [281]: np.einsum('i,j',A,B)
Out[281]: 
array([[ 3,  5],
       [ 6, 10]])
```

Using broadcasting to get the outer

```
In [282]: A[:,None]*B[None,:]
Out[282]: 
array([[ 3,  5],
       [ 6, 10]])
```

What you intend by `[1, 2]'` is implemented in `numpy` as `A[:,None]`, turning the 1d array into a column vector (2d).

Octave added broadcasting long after `numpy` had it.  I don't know if MATLAB has advanced that far or not. :)

`@` doesn't do broadcasting, but can work with the column or row vectors:

```
In [283]: A@B[:,None]       # your imagined A*B'
Out[283]: array([13])
```

To get the outer with `@` I need to add a dimension to make `A` a column vector, and `B` a row vector:

```
In [284]: A[:,None]@B
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
In [285]: A[:,None]@B[None,:]
Out[285]: 
array([[ 3,  5],
       [ 6, 10]])
```

When the arrays really are 2d, and that includes the case where one dimension is 1, the `@`/`dot` behavior isn't that different from common matrix conventions.  It's when dimension is 1, or greater than 2, that intuitions from MATLAB fail, in part because MATLAB doesn't handle those.

This Octave error suggests that n-d matrices just piggy back on 2d ones.  They aren't real n-d in the `numpy` sense.

```
>> ones(2,3,4) * ones(2,3,4)
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 2x12, op2 is 2x12)
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you have a 1d array `one_d` and a 2d array `two_d`, multiplying them with `@` will treat the 1d array in such a way that you get a regular matrix-vector multiplication:

```
one_d @ two_d # gives a row vector (that is returned as 1d array)
two_d @ one_d # gives a column vector (also returned as 1d array)
```

Internally, the 1d array is expanded to a shape (n, 1) or (1, n) array, the multiplication is performed, and then it is converted back to a one-dimensional array.

As to which option is better, the [scipy documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use) recommends arrays.

Comment: hmm, still feels losing control if I have to rely on python to be 'smart' enough to expand the 1d array correctly. For example, what if I have both A = [1, 2] and B = [3, 5] being (2, ) ndarray, A@B could mean [1, 2] * [3, 5]' = 13, or it could mean [1, 2]' * [3, 5] = [[3, 5], [6, 10]]

Comment: Well, yeah, unfortunately it's not obvious what's going to happen without looking at the documentation.